# Error when trying query XML from MAExtension

Tags: xml

I'm writing a FIM MA extension in c# language. What I have is a XML file with some data. I then try to read it in memory from within C# and then query it.

```
    void IMASynchronization.Initialize ()
    {
        XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
        string dir = @"D:\FIM C# Code\FGPP\FGPP\EY.FGPP.AD\FGPP_Group_Membership_Criteria.xml";
        config.Load(dir);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(config.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("dgr", "urn:dgr-schema");
        XmlNode root = config.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Then I call it from within a FlowRule like this:

```
    void IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport( string FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry)
    {

        switch (FlowRuleName)
        {
           case "cd.user:EYAccountType,<dn>->mv.FGPPMember:fgppGroupUID":
                if (csentry["EYAccountType"].IsPresent)
                {
                    XmlNode node;
                    string strADDomain = extractFQDNfromDN(csentry.DN.ToString());
                    string strUserEYAccountType = csentry["EYAccountType"].Value;
                    node = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::dgr:GroupCriteria[dgr:Domain='" + strADDomain + "' and dgr:AccountTypes/dgr:AccountType='" + strUserEYAccountType + "']", nsmgr);

                    if (node != null)
                    {
                        mventry["fgppGroupUID"].Value = node["Name"].InnerText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the management agent, I get the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Mms_ManagementAgent_EY_FGPP_AD.MAExtensionObject.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport(String FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry) in D:\FIM C# Code\FGPP\FGPP\EY.FGPP.AD\EY.FGPP.AD.cs:line 235

Line 235 is:

```
node = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::dgr:GroupCriteria[dgr:Domain='" + strADDomain + "' and dgr:AccountTypes/dgr:AccountType='" + strUserEYAccountType + "']", nsmgr);
```

What am I doing wrong ? :(
GT

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

I had to declare the following variables in the global namespace.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;
XmlNode root;
```

The error was happening because I declared them in the procedure call:

```
void IMASynchronization.Initialize ()
{

}
```

And then I'm using them inside another procedure call:

```
void IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport( string FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry)
{
}
```

The solution is to declare those two variables right at top so they are globally available throughout the MA Extension code. like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Mms_ManagementAgent_EY_FGPP_AD
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MAExtensionObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public class MAExtensionObject : IMASynchronization
    {

        // Declare XML variables
        XmlNode root;
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;
        ...
```

This solves the issue and error disappears.